# Невозможно переключиться на alert с двумя полями ввода (NoAlertPresentException: no such alert)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

Мне нужно автоматически ввести логин и пароль в поля и нажать Войти в alert. Код пишу на Python и использую библиотеку для управления браузерами Selenium WebDriver, браузер Chrome. Почему-то скрипт не видит alert с двумя полями, который мне нужен, следовательно невозможно ввести данные в поля и нажать Войти. Удивляет то, что для такого-же alert с одним полем ввода все работает нормально. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем проблема.

[image: Когда alert с одним полем, то скрипт работает нормально]

[image: Когда alert с двумя полями - скрипт не работает, и не видит alert]

P.S. переключиться на alert пробовал разными способами: driver.switch_to_alert(), driver.switch_to.alert, webdriver.common.alert.Alert(driver), но все тщетно. Также добавлял и убирал ожидание WebDriverWait, тоже не помогло.

Вот кусок кода:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedrivers\\" + chromedriver)
driver.get("https://htmlweb.ru/java/js3.php")  # alert c 1 полем, который работает
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    # alert = driver.switch_to_alert()  # другая попытка переключится на alert
    # alert = driver.switch_to.alert  # другая попытка переключится на alert
    alert = webdriver.common.alert.Alert(driver)
    alert.send_keys("text1")
    # alert.send_keys("text2")  # для второго поля 
    alert.accept()
except:
    for ex in sys.exc_info():
        print(str(ex))
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему передав данные для авторизации сразу в URL:

http://username:password@www.example.com/